# Acceso a los datos dentro de un bucle en el context - Django

Tags: python, django

Espero todo estén bien. Tengo un problema y llego a la comunidad esperando su ayuda! Agradecido de antemano.

Intento hacer unas consultas en Django, mi consulta lo que necesita hacer es saber algunas cifras de algunos usuarios.

Pasa que manejo una estructura de usuarios de tipo pirámide, primero les comparto la explicación de lo que tengo y como lo intento hacer.

Al ingresar al sistema puedo ver los usuarios que yo he creado, de igual manera puedo consultar todo de ellos, y también de su estructura de usuarios, pasa que también manejo varios tipos de usuarios, uno que generan estas "cifras" que son players y otros que son sus moderadores. Yo en este caso quiero consultar los moderadores en un rango de fecha y que me den estas cifras, (como dije ellos no tienen estas cifras y debo consultas los players que pertenezca a el.) y de esta manera pues saber que cifras tiene el moderador en general sin listar todos los players.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    moderador = request.POST.get('id_moderador')

    directa = UserHeritage.objects.filter(direct_creator=moderador).values_list('user__user__id')

    moderadores = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=directa).filter(user__groups__name='Moderadores')

    for moderador in moderadores:
        id_mo = moderador.user_id
        cifras = Ticket.objects.filter(user_id=id_mo).filter(register_date__range=(desde, hasta)).aggregate(cifras=Sum('cifras'))
        bet = cifras['cifras']
        print bet

    context = {'cifras': bet, 'moderadores':moderadores}
    return render(request, self.template_name,context)
```

En el código que comparto tomo el ID enviado desde el form y lo declaro como `moderador` y busco en un modelo `UserHeritage` todos los usuarios que el `moderador` sea el `direct_creator` luego en `UserProfile` busco esos usuarios y solo del grupo moderadores, ya que también puedo crear otro tipo de usuario.

Luego hago un `for` para tomar el ID y trato de traerme todos las cifras de todos los players que existan en esa tabla. Hasta ahí todo va bien, incluso el `print` me da los datos correctos en la consola, pero cuando intento sacarlo por en context como sabrán esta fuera del bucle y me da el ultimo resultado.

Intento meter en context dentro del for y no resulta, intenté hacer una lista para tomar los ID sin hacer el for.

```
ModeradosDict = []
for moderador in moderadores:
   MLista = moderador.user_id
   ModeradosDict.append(MLista)
```

Pero de esa manera me suba TODO, no me suma los players separados, si hay 3 players quiero los monto sumados de los 3 por separados, pero si lo hago por lista me suma esos 3  y me da el resultado, Ya mis conocimientos llegaron hasta ahí, intento estudiar mas, pero necesito hacer esta consulta. Espero haberme explicado correctamente.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si te entendí bien, el segundo `for` que compartes está “resumido”?
Sí no lo has hecho aún, creo que te puede servir algo como:

```
ModeradosDict.append(bet)
```

Y luego en el `context`:

```
context = { ‘cifras’: ModeradosDict, ... }
```

Tal vez como `key` le das el id del moderador y en el template lo comparas con el queryset de moderador que estás enviando en el context.

Comment: No quiero hacer es tener el ID del moderador, con el FOR que trabaja sobre la variable moderador, solo para tener el id, de los moderadores de esa consulta, la variable moderador esta sobre el UserProfile. Solo obtener el ID que lo contengo en la variable id_mo, que después comparo en el modelo ticket. Con el segundo FOR intento traer el numero de ID sin hacer un FOR MLista = moderador.user_id pero me trae el datos como una lista y me suma todo general